# Colspan Bug When using percentage and numbers at same time

Tags: html, css, html-table, percentage

I have a problem working with tables while I wanted to use percentage in `colspan` to split 2 cells in half in a 3 cells table but a bug happened. Now all the other `colspans` in the table have no width and its a mess and I can't use percentage in the 3 cells row as it will be an odd number here's the code:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;" border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">Notify</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="25%">Store</td>
            <td colspan="75%">Logo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">Discount</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>Summer</td>
            <td>Discounts</td>
            <td>Fashion</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="50%">News1</td>
            <td colspan="50%">News2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">News 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">News 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would help people see what your problem is.

Comment: The `colspan` attribute accepts only integer values and not percentage (as correctly Hless answered). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan

Answer (score 4):

This is not how colspan works. You should use width instead.

The attribute colspan accepts a number, not a percentage, and tells the table how many columns a single TD should span across.

For example:

```
 <tr>
    <td width="50%">News1</td>
    <td width="50%">News2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">News 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">News 4</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You done wrong with colspan, that is not take a percent(%) value. You should try like this.

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed;" border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Notify</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Store</td>
        <td >Logo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  colspan="3">Discount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td>Summer</td>
        <td>Discounts</td>
        <td>Fashion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td colspan="2">News1</td>
        <td >News2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  colspan="3">News 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  colspan="3">News 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```